# Multiple on-the-fly filtering in the layers control based on markers' features properties on Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I would like to filter my layer's markers (GeoJSON) according to multiple properties parameters simultaneously.

How can I do this using the layer control?

Example GeoJSON:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -9.2574095,
                    38.7720292
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "state": "G",
                "CCO": "16",
                "PostM_8": "1",
                "PoseM_9": "0",
                "PostM_10": "0",
                "PostM_12": "0",
                "PostB_8_450": "0",
                "CVP ": "0",
                "NR1_D400": "1",
                "NR1_B125": "0",
                "NR2_D400": "0",
                "NR2_B125": "1",
                "NR3_D400": "0",
                "TM_State": "677,4"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -9.250804,
                    38.75554135
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "state": "B",
                "CCO": "16",
                "PostM_8": "1",
                "PostM_9": "0",
                "PostM_10": "1",
                "PostM_12": "0",
                "PostB_8_450": "0",
                "CVP ": "0",
                "NR1_D400": "1",
                "NR1_B125": "0",
                "NR2_D400": "0",
                "NR2_B125": "0",
                "NR3_D400": "0",
                "TM_State ": "1037,3"            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -9.354285,
                    38.72788
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "state": "G",
                "CCO": "14",
                "PostM_8": "1",
                "PostM_9": "1",
                "PostM_10": "0",
                "PostM_12": "0",
                "PostB_8_450": "0",
                "CVP_Redonda": "0",
                "NR1_D400": "0",
                "NR1_B125": "0",
                "NR2_D400": "0",
                "NR2_B125": "0",
                "NR3_D400": "0",
                "TM_State": "940,3"
            }
        }
```

JS:

```
var map = L.map("map", {zoomControl: false}).setView([38.851470, -9.268658], 11);

L.control.zoom({
    position: 'bottomright'
}).addTo(map);

var osm = L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
    {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution:
            '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    });
googleStreets = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
    maxZoom: 20,
    subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3']
});
googleStreets.addTo(map);

//google satellite
googleSat = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
    maxZoom: 20,
    subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3']
});
var url = 'markers.json';

var report = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(url, {
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
        return (feature.properties.PostM_8== "1");
    },
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return new L.marker(latlng, {icon: getIcon(feature.properties.TM_State), draggable: false});
    },
    onEachFeature: setPopup,
    });

var baseMaps = {
    "OSM": osm,
    'Google Street': googleStreets,
    "Google Satellite": googleSat,
};
var overlayMaps = {

};

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps, {collapsed: false}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to create empty "dummy" layer groups which are used just to turn filters for GeoJSON layer on or off when selected/deselected in the layers control. Map `overlayadd` and `overlayremove` events can be used to detect dummy overlay selection/deselection and then set filter for GeoJSON layer and reload data.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
var selectCondition = [];
var selectLayer = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  selectCondition[i] = false;
  selectLayer[i] = L.layerGroup();
  selectLayer[i].myId = i;
}

var overlayMaps = {
  'Condition 1': selectLayer[0],
  'Condition 2': selectLayer[1],
  'Condition 3': selectLayer[2]
};

var baseMaps = {
  "OSM": osm,
  'Google Street': googleStreets,
  "Google Satellite": googleSat,
};

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps, {collapsed: false}).addTo(map);

var report = L.geoJSON(null, {
  filter: function(feature, layer) {
    var cond1 = ((feature.properties.state == 'B') && selectCondition[0]);
    var cond2 = ((feature.properties.CCO == '14') && selectCondition[1]);
    var cond3 = ((feature.properties.NR2_B125 == '1') && selectCondition[2]);
    return (cond1 || cond2 || cond3);
  }
});

var geojsonData;
var url = 'markers.json';
fetch(url)
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(json => {
    geojsonData = json;
    map.addLayer(report);
  });

map.on('overlayadd', function(evt) {
  var i = overlayMaps[evt.name].myId;
  selectCondition[i] = true;
  report.clearLayers();
  report.addData(geojsonData);
});

map.on('overlayremove', function(evt) {
  var i = overlayMaps[evt.name].myId;
  selectCondition[i] = false;
  report.clearLayers();
  report.addData(geojsonData);
});
```

That's how it looks like on the map:

[image]

Comment: Thank you TomazicM, it solved my problem. How can I implement the leaflet-groupedlayercontrol plugin with your suggestion? Thanks

Comment: You want to write your own plugin?

Comment: I want to use the plugin https://github.com/ismyrnow/leaflet-groupedlayercontrol

Comment: This is a separate question and should be posted as a new question, with detailed description of what you want to do and what you have tried thus far.